# How to get rid of useless scrollbars in a material dialog when a radio-group is used?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

This [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-components-dialog-radio?file=src/app/dialog-overview-example-dialog.html) opens a simple dialog which contains a radio group in the [mat-dialog-content](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#dialog-content) div.
You can see that the dialog-content shows an ugly scrollbar:
[image]

This does not happen when other components are used: e.g. input, etc.

Using chrome dev-tools, I can see that the `mat-radio-button`s have a height of `20px`:
[image]

but the `mat-radio-group` only has a height of `17px`:
[image]
Is this a bug in angular material components (the example uses version `12.0.4`), or is there a simple workaround/css that we can use to get rid of the scrollbar?

I've tried explicitly setting the height on the `mat-radio-group`, but this has no effect.

Notes:

- in production we do of course have many dialogs and some of them are large and need the scrollbars
- we need an application wide solution/workaround
- simply hiding the scrollbars is **not** okay: it must remain `auto` so that the dialog can react to size changes (e.g. user rotates device, some items are shown/hidden dynamically, etc.

Comment: change mat-radio-group display property to block then apply height explicitly

Comment: @Chellappanவ I've tried that and we still get the scroll-bar. When I also add a bottom padding of 10px the scrollbar is gone. Could be used as a workaround, but quite nasty...

Comment: The linked Stackblitz looks like you are just throwing raw components into the template which is unlikely to give you good results. Create a flex container for the options? Apply an explicit height to `mat-dialog-content'?

Comment: @SamScholefield We'd like to avoid the complexity of flex for such a simple thing as a list of inputs. This approach works fine for all other components and also all examples on material.angular.io work without flex. Explicit height is not possible, because we want the dialog to resize depending on screen/browser window size (i.e. use the same template for mobile, desktop, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now we came up with a workaround that fixes the issue in all our 30+ dialogs.

The nice thing is that we can apply it in one place, in `styles.scss`:

```css
.mat-dialog-content {
  padding-bottom: 10px !important;
}
```

We just add a padding to the bottom of the dialog content area and then `scrollbars: auto` works as expected in all our dialogs (small and large).  i.e. when you make the browser window larger/smaller, the scrollbar is automatically shown/hidden.

And it also works when there are multiple `mat-radio-group`s in one dialog.
The additional padding between the content and bottom dialog-actions is acceptable for our ui.

[Stackblitz example with workaround](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-components-dialog-radio-workaround?file=src%2Fstyles.scss)

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is due to the ripple effect on the radio button - which takes up additional space and causes the scrollbar to show. See https://github.com/angular/components/issues/20344

There are a number of ways to resolve this, such as using padding or margins on the components or on the dialog content itself like you did. The important thing is that there is enough space added to accommodate the ripple.